# Pass parameters to rendering using ItemRendering in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, rendering

I have a rendering that calls its datasources children. Each child item has a rendering attached in the renderings field.
I am calling

```
@Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering(item)
```

Which works.

However I want to pass some parameters to the child's rendering, so I tried the following code;

```
@Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering(item, new { Parameters = "active=1" })
```

But the parameters do not get passed to the child rendering when I call `@Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Parameters["active"]`

So I tried `@Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering(item, new { Active = 1 })`.  I called it again in the child rendering and still no luck.

Is there a way to pass parameters to the child using `@Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering()`

Comment: Try calling `Model.Rendering.Properties["Active"]` in your view.

Comment: Do I have to pass it in the ItemRendering as new { Parameters = "active=1" } or new { Active = 1 }?

Comment: It should be `new { Active = 1 }`, but I haven't used static binding with parameters in MVC yet

Answer (score 5):

The `ItemRendering` method does not seem to handle properties correctly (or as one would expect!).

A work-around is to use `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering()` instead. You can use this in the same way as the ItemRendering method with the work-around below. Note that you should be setting the "Renderers" field of the datasource item (or its template standard values) rather than the "Renderings" field as you mentioned:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(item["__Renderers"], new {Datasource = item.ID, Message = "Hello World"})
```

In the child rendering, use the `Properties` property, not `Parameters`:

```
@Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.Properties["Message"]
```

Comment: Great catch here, just saw your blog post as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
viewData["active"] = "1";
Html.Sitecore().ItemRendering(ItemToRender, viewData);
```

In the rendering for the Item, you can access the viewdata like this:

```
(ViewData["active"] != null && int.Parse(ViewData["active"].ToString()) == 1)
```